# Form behaviour in windows compact framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am altering an existing windows compact framework application and i did most of the part and i noticed the different behavior of the form.

Consider i am Opening my application, "`ApplicationForm`" is the main form and on clicking Next button in `ApplicationForm` another form say "NextForm" will open.I am using below code to open the `NextForm`.

```
 NextForm obj = new NextForm();
          obj.Showdialog();
```

Now NextForm screen is in open and at this time if I open FileExplorer in device,FileExplorer will open.Now if i Open my installed application from device from Start menu,the application opens with the last open Form say `NextForm`.It will show NextForm in screen but from here if i click Back button in `NextForm` it is taking me to `FileExplorer`.Actually it should take me to  `ApplicationForm` and it works fine when `FileExplorer` is not opened.

1.I need to navigate to `ApplicationForm` if i click Back button in NextForm even if `FileExplorer` is opened in the above scenario.

2.Is it possible to set like this,even the application is opened and the user is in any say `NextForm` form,when user click application from Start menu it should open the ApplicationForm(which is the Main form) and all other form(`NextForm`) should close automatically.

Is it possible to solve this issue.

Comment: You are using ShowDialog, and a Dialog needs closing with Ok|Cancel. Use the navigation aids if you want to use the back buttton.

Comment: @HenkHolterman But if i am not opening FileSxplorer it is working fine.Can you tell me what is "navigation aids" and how to implement this.I am new to windows CF and no idea how to solve this. Please help me.

Comment: The snippet is very inadequate.  My crystal ball says that you are hiding your "ApplicationForm".  So when you close the dialog, your app doesn't have any windows left to give the focus to.  Forcing Windows to find another one that belongs to another application.  You must unhide your main window *before* the dialog closes.

Comment: @HansPassant I am not hiding the  "ApplicationForm".On clicking the button below snippet will call                                                                 private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           NextForm obj = new NextForm();
          obj.Showdialog();
        }.Any idea what could be the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Is it possible to do like this,when user click application from Start menu,it should open "ApplicationForm" and also kill the other forms which opened.

Comment: @HansPassant How to get the existing form instance and kill that form object if new of same form is opened.